# chrome presenting reload confirmation when "beforeunload" event is set

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When I set an non-empty `beforeunload` event of current window, pressing F5 asks for a confirmation:

[image]

Why is that so?

PS: code:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", document_beforeunload, false);
function document_beforeunload() { return true; }
```

If the handler is totally empty, there's no popup.

Comment: What does function `document_beforeunload` return?

Comment: that's what that special "event" does, SNAFU. btw, nice matte.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter: added my js test case.

Comment: "return true" and "true" in dialog, can't you add 1 and 1 together..?

Comment: @dandavis: drinking some right now, want some? :)

Comment: @RobW Are you suggestion the problem is the return true part? Is that specified somewhere that this should be the behaviour?

Comment: @Sebas Yes. If any non-void value is returned, Chrome will display it in the dialog, see docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload

Comment: Ok, I recently switched from onunload to onbeforeunload and was surprised by the difference. This is rather counter intuitive. Problem solved, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function used to handle `onbeforeunload` event should return string to display to user who is about to leave the page.

Your function returns `true` - hence string representation of that is displayed.

It's not the kind of event you can affect by returning true/false. It's only cancelable by user interaction - the function simple returns what to display to the user.

Comment: I didn't know that. Link?